# Git post commit hook - No Git consumers using SCM API plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up a jenkins server on the same vm that git is installed on.

It seems that when I do a push from my laptop jenkins does trigger a build but I get a message each time which I dont understand:

`Scheduled polling of Spring Boot Rest
No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for: git@localhost:/home/git/docker-springboot-rest`

Oddly jenkins does seem to have triggered a build which has detected the change that I pushed but I am assuming something is misconfigured.

I have entered this line into the file /home/git/docker-springboot-rest/hooks/post-receive

`curl http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=git@localhost:/home/git/docker-springboot-rest`

Is there anyone who can help me fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using authentication for jenkins you can trigger a build for a job with a post-receive hook like

```
curl http://[jenkins domain]/job/[job name]/build
```

If you are using authentication, but allowing anonymous read access to jenkins, first set up a build trigger token under the job configuration

[image: Trigger build remotely]

then as your post-receive hook

```
curl http://[jenkins domain]/job/[job name]/build?token=[Token Name]
```

If you have authentication and no anonymous read access then set up a build trigger token as above, but also add a username and User API token to the post receive hook url.  You can look up a User API token by selecting a user from the people screen, then click configure.  On the user configure screen, click the View API token button to see the API token for that user.
This post-receive hook would look like

```
http://[username]:[user API Token]@[jenkins domain]/job/[job name]/build?token=[Token Name]
```

Note: Anonymous read access is found under Manager Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Authorization > Logged-in users can do anything > Allow anonymous read access

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply I will try what you have suggested. Do you know what is the problem with the url that I am calling, or the way that I am doing this?

Comment: I believe the 
http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=git@localhost:/home/git/docker-springboot-rest url is for the git plugin to trigger any builds that are set to poll that git repo.  Under build triggers "Poll SCM" has to be checked and the job configured to check that repo.   I've never been able to get it to work in practice.

Comment: Seems I am in the same boat, I have Poll SCM checked and the job is configured for that repo as I copy pasted the url from jenkins config page. The strange thing is that the build does trigger on push but I get that message printed in my terminal after I do the git push. Thanks for the solution.